# Stripping comments line from a string

Tags: python, string, parsing, text

I have a string variable that contains the input from a big text file. The comments in the text file begin with a '#' and end with new line.

So, what I would like to do is generate another string from this string where all these comment lines beginning with '#' and ending with newline are removed.

So, I thought I could do something where I could split the string as:

```
def transform_string(input):
    output = ''
    # Look for #
    sub_strs = input.split('#')
    for s in sub_strs:
        # Look for newline
        sub_sub_strs = s.split('\r\n')
        for j in sub_sub_strs:
            output += j

return output
```

However, it seems ugly and I am wondering if there is a more elegant., pythonic way to do this. Also, this is quite prone to error. As each '#' will have one corresponding newline and I would like to do split at the first occurrence rather than split at all '\r\n', I think.

Comment: Are the comments always whole lines? If so, it would be easier to process the file as a list of lines rather than one long string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generator is possibly the most Pythonic solution here:

```
def clean_input(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
                yield line

for line in clean_input('somefile.txt'):
    ...
```

This allows you to move the comment stripping, or any other pre-processing you need away from the actual processing of the file where you can just iterate over the cleaned data.

Comment: Lots of great answers but I could choose only one! I ended up going with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions could work:

```
# Python 2.7
import re

def stripComment(text): return re.sub(r'#.*$', '', text)

print(stripComment("Hello there"))
# Hello there

print(stripComment("Hello #there"))
# Hello
```

This should allow handling of comments that are entire lines, or line where the comments start somewhere in the middle (the content prior to the comments are preserved)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you're reading from a text file, you're best off doing this as you read the file in:

```
data = []
with open("input_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith("#"):
            data.append(line)

data = "".join(data)
```

This last concatenation step is less than optimal -- if you can, you should deal with each line separately so you don't need the whole file in memory.

Comment: Or a list comp - `data = [line for line in f if not line.startswith("#")]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension to filter the lines:

```
>>> txt = """some lines
... #some commented
... some not
... #othe comment
... other line"""
>>> '\n'.join(line for line in txt.splitlines() if not line.startswith('#'))
'some lines\nsome not\nother line'
```